# Field on object not accessible in Report Builder

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, survey, salesforce-survey

We recently started using Salesforce's Survey tool and are having trouble reporting on it.

When I look at a SurveyInvitation in Lightning, one of the fields I can see is "Participant", and I can also see that field in the Object Manager for SurveyInvitation. Here is what I see in Lightning Experience:

[image: SurveyInvitiation]

I've created a straightforward custom report type to report on SurveyInvitations. However, in the "Fields Available for Reports" section, there is no Participant field.

Why is this? Is there any way to make the field available for reporting? I have already checked in Object Manager that it is not a field-level security issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to setup, report types, edit your custom report and include the field you want for that to show up in your report

Comment: @Raj I've already included all available fields in the custom report. The Participant field doesn't appear in the list of Survey Invitations Fields that I can select from.

Comment: participant is a polymorphic field to user or contact; is there a standard report you can customize instead?

Comment: I'm assuming the field is a lookup field. In that case, can you please check FLS for that object, just in case. I mean if it is not a direct lookup but like a third level lookup or something. Lookup of a lookup etc..

Comment: @cropredy There are no standard reports for Surveys or any of the related objects, even the SF docs say to report on these you should create a custom report type

Comment: @Raj You're right, it's a data lookup field. Lookup(User, Contact, Lead). Which fields should I check the FLS of on those objects?

Comment: @James Do you see the participant field in the related lists if you already have Survery Invitation related list to Contact / User / Lead objects? Also, here is the URL, i think it is a know issue from Salesforce for participant not being available. check if your org falls into this..

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KPPOQA4

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reference_report_object.htm&type=5 suggests you do the CRT on `SurveyQuestionResponses` where `CreatedBy.FullName` is the participant.

Answer (score 1):

The participant of a survey is always a lead or a contact or a user. SurveyInvitation object has 3 different fields - LeadId, ContactId and UserId which look like they're integrated in one field onthe UI i.e. Participant. User the 3 different fields to get the records. They're lookup fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In reports, you will have a field called 'Response Name', that stores the participant name. You can use that to get the participant details.

[image]